# Javascript form validation submit button issue

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is that the code works absolutely fine for displaying the validation errors once I click on the submit button, but after the messages are displayed.. and again when I click on the submit button (without reloading ie. the error messages are still on the display), it redirects to the success page even though it has error messages.

Have a look at the code:

```js
var flag = 0;

function username() {
  usrn = document.form1.txt.value;
  if (usrn == "") {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "Please enter a username";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (usrn.length < 8) {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "minimum 8 characters required";
    flag = 1;
  }

}

function password() {
  pass = document.form1.pass.value;
  cpass = document.form1.cpass.value;
  if (pass == "") {
    document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = "Please enter a password";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (pass.length < 8) {
    document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = "minimum 8 characters required";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (cpass == "") {
    document.getElementById("cpassword").innerHTML = "Please confirm password";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (cpass != pass) {
    document.getElementById("cpassword").innerHTML = "passwords do not match";
    flag = 1;
  } else
    return;
}

function cpassword() {
  cpass = document.form1.cpass.value;
  pass = document.form1.pass.value;
  if (cpass == "") {
    document.getElementById("cpassword").innerHTML = "Please confirm password";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (cpass != pass) {
    document.getElementById("cpassword").innerHTML = "passwords do not match";
    flag = 1;
  } else
    return;
}

function email() {
  email = document.form1.em.value;
  if (email == "") {
    document.getElementById("emailid").innerHTML = "Please enter Email-ID";
    flag = 1;
  }
}

function check(form) {
  flag = 0;
  username();
  password();
  email();
  if (flag == 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="success.html" onSubmit="return check(this)" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <caption>FILL FORM</caption>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="txt">Enter Username</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txt">
        <div class="error" id="user" onBlur="username()"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="pass">Enter Password</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" id="pass" onBlur="password()">
        <div class="error" id="password"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="cpass">Confirm Password</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" id="cpass" onBlur="password()">
        <div class="error" id="cpassword"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="em">Enter Email-ID</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="email" id="em" onBlur="email()">
        <div class="error" id="emailid"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

thank you

Comment: Please edit your question using Stackoverflow code blocks to create a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet to work with.

There are few issues in the code:

- In the function `email()`, you are assigning value to the `email` variable.
- There are many variables created NOT within the function scope.
- More optimizations can be made rather than using `global` functions and variables which will make the code more readable and maintainable.

```js
var flag = 0;

function username() {
  var usrn = document.form1.txt.value;
  if (usrn == "") {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "Please enter a username";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (usrn.length < 8) {
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "minimum 8 characters required";
    flag = 1;
  }

}

function password() {
  var pass = document.form1.pass.value;
  var cpass = document.form1.cpass.value;
  if (pass == "") {
    document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = "Please enter a password";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (pass.length < 8) {
    document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = "minimum 8 characters required";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (cpass == "") {
    document.getElementById("cpassword").innerHTML = "Please confirm password";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (cpass != pass) {
    document.getElementById("cpassword").innerHTML = "passwords do not match";
    flag = 1;
  } else
    return;
}

function cpassword() {
  var cpass = document.form1.cpass.value;
  var pass = document.form1.pass.value;
  if (cpass == "") {
    document.getElementById("cpassword").innerHTML = "Please confirm password";
    flag = 1;
  } else if (cpass != pass) {
    document.getElementById("cpassword").innerHTML = "passwords do not match";
    flag = 1;
  } else
    return;
}

function email() {
  var emailValue = document.form1.em.value;
  if (emailValue == "") {
    document.getElementById("emailid").innerHTML = "Please enter Email-ID";
    flag = 1;
  }
}

function check(form) {
  flag = 0;
  username();
  password();
  email();
  if (flag == 1) {
    console.log("False");
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log("True");
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="success.html" onsubmit="return check(this)" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <caption>FILL FORM</caption>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="txt">Enter Username</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txt">
        <div class="error" id="user" onBlur="username()"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="pass">Enter Password</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" id="pass" onBlur="password()">
        <div class="error" id="password"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="cpass">Confirm Password</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" id="cpass" onBlur="password()">
        <div class="error" id="cpassword"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="em">Enter Email-ID</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="email" id="em" onBlur="email()">
        <div class="error" id="emailid"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

whenever there is validation error. return false from the function. it should fix this.